# URL that hide my $_GET parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have a problem with URL and get method form.
Here's my step-1 URL :

http://localhost/myproject/media.php?module=create

And here's my current URL (step-2) when I submit the data :

http://localhost/myproject/media.php?module=create&code=J-001&year=T-016&dept=P-001&class=KG-A&semester=1&day=monday

Is it possible to replace my current URL (step-2) into short URL ? or, is it possible to makes URL that hide my $_GET parameter?

Im currently try editing .htaccess but still cant get it right:

Options +FollowSymlinks

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^index.php$ media.php?module=create [L]
RewriteRule ^test-([0-9]+)/([0-9-0-9a-zA-Z\w]+)/?$ media.php?module=create&code=$1&year=$2&dept=$3&class=$4&semester=$5&day=$6 [NC]

#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule ^test-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$ media.php?module=create&code=$1&year=$2&dept=$3&class=$4&semester=$5&day=$6  [L]
#Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: How exactly do you want the URL to be? Meaning how do you want it to look in the browser. Part of you problem is you're not capturing all the parts of the URL you want but you are using the variable as if you had.

Comment: `0-9-0-9a-zA-Z\w` is redundant, a character class is a list of allowed characters/ranges. The `0-9` twice does nothing new on the second instance. Further the `\w` includes `0-9a-zA-Z_` so you only need `\w+` there and you don't need a character class at all.

Comment: @PanamaJack honestly i want the URL that hide my $_GET parameter, is it possible ?

Comment: why dont you **POST** ?

Comment: @bub its like form wizard, i'd like to get the data then ill call it later

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about htaccess but as far as I know every part that is captured (between parenthesis) in the regular expression is mapped into a $1(or any other number - depending on the order) in the resulting url.

so

```
RewriteRule ^test-([0-9]+)/([0-9-0-9a-zA-Z\w]+)/?$ media.php?module=create&code=$1&year=$2&dept=$3&class=$4&semester=$5&day=$6
```

only captures 2, and tries to map them to 6 different options.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what it seems like you're trying to do.

Your URL would have to look like this

```
http://example.com/J-001/T-016/P-001/KG-A/1/Monday
```

Then you can have a rewrite rule like so.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ media.php?module=create&code=$1&year=$2&dept=$3&class=$4&semester=$5&day=$6 [NC,L]
```